# Can alpha, beta or gamma particles induce fission?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, radioactivity

Nuclear weapons and reactors get their chain reactions underway via neutron radiation, but do other radiation particles ever contribute?

Comment: It's important to keep in mind the distinction between fission and *chain reaction* fission, where the neutrons from one fission event go on to trigger further fissions.

Answer (score 2):

Gamma initiated fission is well known, being studied from the very beginning of nuclear physics (lots of work using photofission to understand energy levels in light nuclei) . A little-known feature of the Evaluated Nuclear Data Files is that it has evaluated cross sections for gammas as well as for neutrons. I use the mirror at [Brookhaven](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/exfor/endf00.jsp).

As an example, I enter '238U' for the Target, 'g,*' for the Reaction (not noted in the suggested list to the left - sigh), and 'sig' for the Quantity, hit return, and get a listing of 5 different types of gamma cross sections. If I select the "U238(G,F),SIG" (yes, "F" for Fission, not Fluorine) entry and plot it I get:

[image]